# What is type int(*)[]

Tags: c++, oop

I've class with matrix and getter

```
class A
{
  int matrix[20][10];
 public:
   auto getter(){return matrix;}
};
```

What is a type that `auto` returned?
And how to return it without using `auto`

Comment: Why should one care. Use auto and your life is easy :) And also your title says the type ;)

Comment: your title and your text are two complementary questions... the answer for one is the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to specify the return type without `auto` or a type alias. The usual rules for declarators make it quite ugly. But here it is, just follow the spiral rule:

```
int (*getter())[10] {return matrix;}
```

Comment: OK, How to do convertation to this type? It does not work `((*)[10])matrix`

Comment: @Hujuk - I see you joined only recently, so welcome to [SO]! This is not a discussion forum, it's a Q&A platform. We ask questions, and receive answers. If you have a new question, please [post it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), instead of asking in comments. Read [ask] to learn more.

Comment: @Hujuk - Also, please note I posted a complete function definition. I didn't say you need to convert anything by casting.

Comment: @StroryTeller Ok, I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`auto` here gets the type that the function should return automatically. In that case that type is:

```
int (*)[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Auto means type is going to be decided according to what you returned. So in this case i believe it is and array that holds int arrays. You can just put the type you want to return instead of auto.